# python - looking for factory of db drivers

Tags: python, database

It looks like MySQLdb, psycopg2 and cx_Oracle have pretty simillar interfaces for coneccting to databases. So it sounds reasonable to create a factory that someone can use like this:

```
conn = DBDriverFactory("MySQL", connectionDetails)
```

But first I want to ensure that:

1. I'm not missing some better solution and my idea is not really stupid.
2. There isn't any well known working solution like that to prevent from reinventing a wheel.

I know django and alchemy should do these things but I'm looking for something very lightweight and simple (but efficient and elegant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this doesn't exist as a "lightweight and simple" solution is that most SQL database engines use different SQL syntax, different DB-API parameterization and sometimes subtly different semantics, so changing database is not as simple as changing the DB-API module to use. A real abstraction would require parsing the SQL and generating new SQL appropriate for the database in use.

I don't know of any package that tries to do this, as the common approach (and much easier) is to generate engine-specific SQL from a more easily parsable form (like the classes ORM's like SQLAlchemy and Django's ORM have you create.)

Comment: My impression about common interface is based on the fact, that all mentioned db backends expose cursor object, with execute, fetchone and fetchall methods. For simple operations like insert, select, update, delete this shoud be sufficient and differences in SQL dialects should be negligible.

Comment: The DB-API specifies the functions, classes and methods that the database modules should expose, yes. You're still left with different paramstyles as well as many, many differences in actual SQL syntax. Just the paramstyle issue alone means a "common subset" of the SQL syntax of just two different database engines would be really quite, quite limited.